# Privileged access groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Anyone have any clues how to manage eligible assignments in privileged access enabled groups with PowerShell?

Get-AzureADMSGroup shows the group IsAssignableToRole is True and Get-AzureADGroupMember shows no members as they're not directly assigned.

The AzureAdPreview module has a number of commands to manage PIM roles. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#privileged-role-management

But with privileged access groups, I can't work out the commands to assign eligible user assignments to a group rather than to a role.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you please try the below Command to add the user to your required group --

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Groupname -Members user1,user2

Groupname - Please mention the name of group.

User1 - 1st user ;
User2 - 2nd User

Please have a look this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) if it helps you.

Thank You.